# Ho to use File.Encrypt correctly in C#?

Tags: c#, encryption

i'm trying to use the [**File.Encrypt**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.encrypt?view=net-7.0) function to encrypt a `.txt` file.

```
{
   File.AppendAllText(settingsPath, "Save_System;\n" + "Game_Sessions;\n" + "Sound;\n" + "User_OS;");                       
   File.Encrypt(settingsPath);
}
```

The **Encrypt** method throws an exception:

> System.IO.IOException: This request is not supported.

Can someone help me please? Thank you a lot!

Comment: ...have you read [the documentation for `File.Encrypt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.encrypt?view=net-7.0)? The article explains that the `Encrypt` method only works if you're using Windows **and** are using NTFS **and** have EFS enabled - most people do not have all 3, so `File.Encrypt` cannot be used in most cases. Instead, consider using DPAPI instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-use-data-protection

Comment: _"This request is not supported"_ - that error message is very straightforward: it means you cannot use `File.Encrypt` on your computer - so how are you expecting anyone to make it magically work for you?

Comment: `File.Encrypt` controls NTFS encryption. This is an NTFS feature on non-Home Windows versions. On Pro/Enterprise or Server, EFS (the feature) is on by default. Home doesn't have it at all. One could argue `Encrypt` shouldn't be a member of `File` in the first place due to these restrictions

Comment: NTFS support in .NET was always a bit of a *huge* mess. NTFS has journaling, snapshots, encryption, compression, object access, tons of metadata. And yet, .NET Framework only offered `File.Encrypt`. In .NET Core/.NET 5 things are no better, as *Linux* file systems offer even more features, with a greater variety. And we still can't access them